# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una tabulación al contenido CSS de nth-of-type():before { content: "Unidad: "; }?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente problema en CSS3, debo agregar una tabulación después del ":" dentro del "content"

```
.tablaSales td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Unidad:"; }
```

Probé añadiendo los marcadores habituales de `&nbsp;` o `&#160;` y me sale explícitamente como cadena de caracteres, inclusive escapando con `\` no lo consigo hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo con el unicode del espacio: `\00a0`

```css
div::before {
  content: "Unidad:\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ";  
}
```

```html
<div>Contenido</div>
```

Comment: Brillante! Muchas gracias